How do I run multiple BackgroundWorkers that use the same code at the same time in Visual Basic
I want to monitor several folders at the same time and when files arrive process them synchronously.  To get a handle on the structure I'm starting by just trying to report the number of files in each folder. (I could do this looping one by one but in the eventual solution I'll be importing large quantities of files from each folder and want to process them simultaneously). I've read numerous threads (about threads and tasks) but can't seem to find anything close.  I've used background workers in the past and have tried this approach but this gives me an error saying the BW is busy.
Here's where I am so far:
'GET EACH FOLDER PATH and send to the BW
For x As Integer = 0 To SitelistBS.Count - 1
    Dim ThisSite As New Site
    ThisSite.SiteID = SitelistBS.Current("SiteID")
    ThisSite.InboxPath = SitelistBS.Current("InboxPath")
    BWI1.RunWorkerAsync(argument:=ThisSite)
    SitelistBS.MoveNext()
Next

Private Sub BWI1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BWI1.DoWork
    Dim ThisSite As Site
    ThisSite = e.Argument
    Dim InboxPath As String = ThisSite.InboxPath
    Dim Files = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(InboxPath, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.*")
    Dim SiteInboxStatusResults As New SiteInboxStatus
    SiteInboxStatusResults.SiteID = ThisSite.SiteID
    SiteInboxStatusResults.FileCount = Files.Count
    e.Result = SiteInboxStatusResults
End Sub

Private Sub BWI1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BWI1.RunWorkerCompleted
    Dim SiteInboxStatusResults As New SiteInboxStatus
    SiteInboxStatusResults = e.Result
    RTB.Text += SiteInboxStatusResults.SiteID
    RTB.Text += SiteInboxStatusResults.FileCount
End Sub

